# How to add an element at the end of ListView.builder to move back to the top?

Tags: flutter

How can I add an element to the end of a `Listview.builder` which allows the user to click it and make him go back to the top of the list?

Comment: inside the builder property of this listviewbuilder, check if index == length of true then add the additional widget with he last widget with the help of column. Add a listener to your scroll widget and do the rest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass a scroll controller to `ListView.builder` and add one to item count which is used to add "back to top" button as the last item. Then you can use listView controller to scroll the list to top when user tap on the last item of the list.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: items.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => (index != items.length)
            ? ListTile(title: Text(items[index]))
            : ListTile(
                leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                    onPressed: _navigateToTop),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToTop() {
    final Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: 400);
    final Curve curve = Curves.ease;
    if (_controller.hasClients) {
      var scrollPosition = this._controller.position;

      scrollPosition.animateTo(
        0,
        duration: duration,
        curve: curve,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: very nice       .It works good

Comment: Messing with indexes in a list is bad. Generally using indexes is bad. Better solution is what OMi Shah suggested in comment. Anytime you artificially alter indexes you are bound for array index out of bounds exceptions and problems.